# Building a regex to extract domains ONLY

Tags: python, regex, capture

I am looking to create a regex in python in order to extract ONLY the domains from the following the set of URLs at the bottom of this post. I have been using https://regexr.com/ in order to test out my regex before applying `Series.str.extract()`. So far, I have been able to get VERY close, but it looks like the first character (the first 'w' in www, where there is one included) is not being captured. The regex I have so far is this:

`[^\/\/](\w*.\w*.com|\w*.\w*.org|\w*.\w*.cc|\w*.\w*.ly)`

How can I modify this to go from `http://css-cursor.techstream.org` to only `css-cursor.techstream.org`

```
'https://www.amazon.com/Technology-Ventures-Enterprise-Thomas-Byers/dp/0073523429',
 'http://www.interactivedynamicvideo.com/',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2007/11/07/movies/07stein.html?_r=0',
 'http://evonomics.com/advertising-cannot-maintain-internet-heres-solution/',
 'HTTPS://github.com/keppel/pinn',
 'Http://phys.org/news/2015-09-scale-solar-youve.html',
 'https://iot.seeed.cc',
 'http://www.bfilipek.com/2016/04/custom-deleters-for-c-smart-pointers.html',
 'http://beta.crowdfireapp.com/?beta=agnipath',
 'https://www.valid.ly?param',
 'http://css-cursor.techstream.org'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the regex a hard requirement, because you need to combine it with an existing regex? If not there's an easy tool in the standard library that does it:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urls = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/Technology-Ventures-Enterprise-Thomas-Byers/dp/0073523429',
    'http://www.interactivedynamicvideo.com/',
    'http://www.nytimes.com/2007/11/07/movies/07stein.html?_r=0',
    'http://evonomics.com/advertising-cannot-maintain-internet-heres-solution/',
    'HTTPS://github.com/keppel/pinn',
    'Http://phys.org/news/2015-09-scale-solar-youve.html',
    'https://iot.seeed.cc',
    'http://www.bfilipek.com/2016/04/custom-deleters-for-c-smart-pointers.html',
    'http://beta.crowdfireapp.com/?beta=agnipath',
    'https://www.valid.ly?param',
    'http://css-cursor.techstream.org',
]

domains = [urlparse(url).netloc for url in urls]
print(domains)
```

Well I guess the regex is faster:

```
>>> netloc = re.compile(r'^https?://([^/?^]+)', flags=re.I)                                                                                                    
>>> %timeit [netloc.match(url).group(1) for url in urls]                                                                                                       
5.66 µs ± 97.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> %timeit [urlparse(url).netloc for url in urls]                                                                                                             
23.3 µs ± 3.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Hi! I was being asked to do this as part of an exercise to practice working with a regex. I appreciate you showing me urlparse! Currently working on figuring out what a non-capturing group is.

Comment: @Willy_Golden Have fun learning a powerful tool. If you are having trouble getting to grips with them, you could try a different point of view: and practise turning a given regex into a finite state automaton. I find approaching a subject from different angles helps forming the right intuition. And formal language theory [can be very amusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/383793)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed it a bit to the following expression:

`[^\/\/]([\w\-.]*\.(?:org|com|cc|ly))`

1. The `.` before the TLD is now escaped using `\` (`\.`, which means the character `.` and not "every character").
2. I've added `-` and `.` to the host name (not only `\w`).
3. I've grouped the TLDs (org, com, cc, ly) into a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) - just to make the regular expression looks cleaner and eliminate repetitions.

Comment: `sre_constants.error: bad character range \w-. at position 9`. (You need to backlash-escape the `-` or put it at the beginning or end of the character class.)

Answer (score 0):

According to regexr.com, this should do what you want and is simpler:
`(?<=\/\/)([^/?']*)` .  After all, the domain is literally everything after the // up to the next / or ? or end of string.

Comment: I just tested this and it does not actually work! Your solution seems to include the bacslahses, and in one case, http!

Comment: Are you testing the strings separately, or are you including the apostrophes?  You can fix it for the apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

For the example data, you can use an alternation for `com` `org` `ly` and `cc` and escape the dot to match it literally.

To match `css-cursor.techstream.org` you can use a repeated group matching either `-` or `.`

Note that `[^\/\/]` is the same as `[^/]` and matches any char except a `/`

```
\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\.(?:ly|org|com|cc)\b
```

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:[.-]\w+)*` Optionally repeat matching either `.` or `-` and 1+ word chars
- `\.` Match a liter dot (note to escape it)
- `(?:ly|org|com|cc)` Non capture group, match any of the alternatives
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oRPFgZ/1)

If you also want to match the protocol, you can use a capture group for the string that you want.

```
\bhttps?://(\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\.(?:ly|org|com|cc))\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nRXFD/1)

Answer (score 0):

I added literal dot . and - dash to the regular expression

```
data=['https://www.amazon.com/Technology-Ventures-Enterprise-Thomas- 
 Byers/dp/0073523429',
 'http://www.interactivedynamicvideo.com/',
 'http://www.nytimes.com/2007/11/07/movies/07stein.html?_r=0',
 'http://evonomics.com/advertising-cannot-maintain-internet-heres-solution/',
 'HTTPS://github.com/keppel/pinn',
 'Http://phys.org/news/2015-09-scale-solar-youve.html',
 'https://iot.seeed.cc',
 'http://www.bfilipek.com/2016/04/custom-deleters-for-c-smart-pointers.html',
 'http://beta.crowdfireapp.com/?beta=agnipath',
 'https://www.valid.ly?param',
 'http://css-cursor.techstream.org']

import re

pattern = re.compile(r'https?://([\w.\.\-]+)')

for data in data:
     match = pattern.match(data)
     if match:
         print(match.group(1))
```

output:

```
www.amazon.com
www.interactivedynamicvideo.com
www.nytimes.com
evonomics.com
iot.seeed.cc
www.bfilipek.com
beta.crowdfireapp.com
www.valid.ly
css-cursor.techstream.org
```